# Regular expression for an email address not end with </a>

Tags: ruby, regex, regex-negation

I want to use regex in ruby to capture the plain text email address but NOT the email address surrounded by mailto link tags (like `<a href="" class="" >a@b.com</a>`), tried `source.gsub(/(?!<$)[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}/i)` but this does not work

Comment: Are you parsing HTML? Why not use an HTML parser and simply grab the text content of that element?

Comment: Are you aware that you [can't parse HTML with a regexp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2483313), because HTML isn't a regular language?

Answer (score 0):

`/(\w+@[\w.-]+|\{(?:\w+, *)+\w+\}@[\w.-])(?!<\/a>)*$/i`

So something like `source.gsub(/(\w+@[\w.-]+|\{(?:\w+, *)+\w+\}@[\w.-])(?!<\/a>)*$/i)`

Here's the regex statement, I took the liberty of using a different e-mail selector as well.

`(?!<\/a>)*$` basically says ignore it if this ends in `</a>`. It might be more efficient though to just filter out any `<a></a>` tags first if you're expecting multiple email addresses per line / document.

Comment: Thank for your answer, unfortunately, the regex doesn't capture either email address end with </a> tag or the plain text one...